# ASP MVC 5 EF 6 - Insert into Multiple Tables

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, relational-database

I have an existing database, from which I have built a shell web-app using VS2013 and EF6, but I have run into a few problems.

My database has the following tables, for example:

```
Table: Customer (Id, First, Last, Date)
Table: Assets (Id, CustID)
Table: Orders (Id, AssetId, CustID)
```

When the EF created the shell webapp for me (which has awesome) it gave me the following method, for example, to create a new Customer:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Id, First, Last, Date")] Customer customer)
....
return View(customer)
```

In my database I have a *one* Customer to *many* orders and assets, but I don't understand how to use this relationship during a Create operation, or any other.

**My question** -- How do I "Create" a new **Customer** when this operation needs to span multiple tables?  For example, when the "Create Customer" form is filled out, you would add one or more **Assets** and/or **Orders**.

Should I use a stored procedure to do multiple inserts across three different tables?  Or can I make a change to the database that will let me use all the EF magic?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think what I'm actually asking here is how to use multiple classes within a single form submit?

Comment: It sounds like your controller is using the domain model where you want to be using a view model instead (and then map the view model to your domain model in your Post action).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a view model that contains all three classes.

```
public class CreateCustomerViewModel
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Your `[HttpGet]` action method will pass this view model as the model instead of a `Customer`.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    CreateCustomerViewModel model = new CreateCustomerViewModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

Your `[HttpPost]` action method will take the `CreateCustomerViewModel` as a parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateCustomerViewModel model)
{
    // Create the Customer with the necessary Assets and Orders and save
}
```

If you're classes and relationships are configured properly, adding the appropriate Assets and Orders to the navigation properties on your `Customer` entity should trigger EF to automatically insert the assets and orders into the appropriate tables when you insert the `Customer`.